# PHP - file_put_contents . How to suppress ouput of it?

Tags: php

When I try to create a file with file_put_contents then it also outputs the file directly in the browser.

Code:

```
file_put_contents($file, utf8_encode($seite));
```

Is there a way to suppress this output? Documentation seems to not have a solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't send anything to the client. Check your code if you output the file contents somewhere else. Maybe an `echo` you forgot to remove?

Answer (score -1):

UTF-8 and file_put_contents does not work, try this:

```
<?php
$f = fopen($file, 'w+');
fwrite($f, $seite);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: And how is this related to the question? Besides that, why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but utf8 and file_put_contents work fine together. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php